# Is it possible to run OSX daemons with asleep or locked-screen mode?

Tags: macos, cocoa, daemon

In OSX/Cocoa I'm creating a daemon to be run in given intervals of a day. AFAK, daemons are executed independently of logged users and so, in other words, it is run even with locked screen isn't it?

In my approach, I've created of a .plist file in the /Library/LaunchDaemons that describes my daemon. I've set the label, ProgramArguments, StartCalendarInterval, and UserName. All is correct, and by triggering launchctl load at console, the daemon runs OK;

Problem comes when my computer is asleep or screen-locked. Every time that my daemon executes, it send an email to me in the end of its execution, and it appears that the daemon is not running.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If the Mac is a sleep then nothing will run as only the RAM is kept "alive".  You'd have to set the power settings to never sleep.

Comment: Hi Droppy, thank you for replying. I'm not talking about "power-off" but only "asleep/lock" mode. I'm searching a bit here, and I've found SleepWatcher: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060908113605812. Not know for sure if it can help me...

Comment: Yeah that seems to work on the trigger to/from sleep mode, not during.

Comment: Hmm... looks like so. Do you know an approach to run a task, at least, with locked-screen? Suppose I've just put the machine with shift-control-eject (lock). I'd like to run the daemon in these situations. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Daemons should work while not logged on or locked, but the key is if the Mac is configured to sleep or not.  An admin user can change that if they wish, but the default is to sleep during lock.

Comment: Ok. Well, I think that I'll just ask for the users to configure their machines to not enter in sleep mode. I've find in Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/ScheduledJobs.html (last topic) that I can do nothing when computer enters in asleep. I'll close the question here. thank you very much!